# Are Chinese wet markets selling bat again?

Tags: china, covid-19, meat

I read that [China banned consumption of wild life](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/03/05/asia/china-coronavirus-wildlife-consumption-ban-intl-hnk/index.html) a few weeks ago.

> A strict ban on the consumption and farming of wild animals is being rolled out across China in the wake of the deadly coronavirus epidemic, which is believed to have started at a wildlife market in Wuhan.

However, there are a lot of rumors that Chinese wet markets are selling bat meat again. For example, [a 29 March 2020 Daily Mail article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8163761/Chinese-markets-selling-bats.html) claims:

> Chinese markets are still selling bats and slaughtering rabbits on blood-soaked floors

Are Chinese wet markets regularly selling bat meat again?

Comment: I'm not quite seeing how this is notable claim. Is nobody breaking any phytosanitary law anywhere? Unless we quantify "are still selling bats" this is like saying "people still exceed the speed limit on highways".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the claim itself is too vague and unremarkable.

Comment: @Fizz A Corona-related strain was traced in a bat, suggesting that consumption of wildlife in contact with bats (e.g. pangolin) is one potential cause behind the pandemic that we're currently facing. This is exactly why this "rumor" is spreading, and is creating quite an anti-chinese sentiment. If you can't understand why I take this as notable I can't help you.

Comment: @FooBar: yes, also in the news "people are still getting murdered [sometimes]". "Regularly" is not even in the quoted claim, you've added it.

Comment: @Fizz indeed, I'm trying to make that claim into something that is more meaningful. Of course, some wet market somewhere could always defy a governmental regulation, that would not be "noteable". But is this something that happens regularly, i.e. widespread?

Comment: Feel free to change the qualifier "regularly" into something that you feel is a better tradeoff between quantifiable and meaningful.

Comment: China is not the only country that sells live critters for food. If it weren't for covid-19, this would be the time of year I would be driving to a local seafood market in search of live crawfish. A Louisiana crawfish boil is something to behold, but the crawfish need to be alive just before being dropped into the pot. At other times in the year, that same seafood market would be selling live crabs and lobsters, live clams and mussels, and live octopus and squid. If one is willing to pay a stiff price, some sell live fish.

Comment: So you're saying a Louisiana crawfish boil started COVID?

Comment: This is a valid question. The answer appears to be no. There's new legislation that will handle this but right not it seems to be unclear. Media definitely isn't reporting on it.